Best way to hide platform-specific type in C++ header
I am creating a cross-platform font rasterization class that uses platform-specific types across macOS, Linux, and Windows. The header is basically the same, except NativeFontType should be substituted with the platform-specific type. Let's call this type T.
Below is my second attempt. I forward-declare a NativeFontType struct, then I define it with a single member of type T in each implementation. This is nearly perfect, but I really want to define NativeFontType as T itself without the wrapper struct. Is this possible?
If not, I'm open to alternative approaches! Do note that the native font types are all wrapped in smart pointer types (e.g., ComPtr on Windows). If there is a neat way to express T as some kind of SmartPtr<T>, that may also work.
The main goal is to avoid including the platform header in font_rasterizer.h. The user of my class does not need to know about T.
// font_rasterizer.h

class FontRasterizer {
public:
    size_t addFont(std::string_view font_name8, int font_size, FontStyle style = FontStyle::kNone);
    size_t addSystemFont(int font_size, FontStyle style = FontStyle::kNone);
    const Metrics& metrics(size_t font_id) const;

    RasterizedGlyph rasterize(size_t font_id, uint32_t glyph_id) const;
    LineLayout layoutLine(size_t font_id, std::string_view str8);

private:
    // Problem: How do I make this type directly into the platform-specific type I want without the struct wrapper aspect?
    struct NativeFontType;

    std::unordered_map<std::string, size_t> font_postscript_name_to_id;
    std::vector<NativeFontType> font_id_to_native;
    std::vector<Metrics> font_id_to_metrics;
    size_t cacheFont(NativeFontType ct_font);
};

// core_text_rasterizer.cc

#include <CoreText/CoreText.h>  // Platform-specific header.

struct FontRasterizer::NativeFontType {
    ScopedCFTypeRef<CTFontRef> font;
};

// pango_rasterizer.cc

#include <pango/pangocairo.h>  // Platform-specific header.

struct FontRasterizer::NativeFontType {
    GObjectPtr<PangoFont> font;
};

// directwrite_rasterizer.cc

#include <dwrite.h>  // Platform-specific header.

struct FontRasterizer::NativeFontType {
    ComPtr<IDWriteFont> font;
};


You rather want to use Pimpl

Create an abstract base class (interface) and a factory method returning an std::unique_ptr to that interface. This also allows you to easily create stubs/mocks for unit testing (that simulate things that can go wrong at the os level)

@PepijnKramer That sounds good! If you have the time, would you mind submitting a basic example of this? That would also let me mark your answer as accepted.

@3CxEZiVlQ Do you have an example of PIMPL here? I actually used it for my first attempt, but instead I shoved everything in the private section (members, NativeFontType, etc.) into the PIMPL class. This was less maintainable, however. How would you use it in this context?

Since you need a std::vector of hidden type, PIMPL is becomes a tad complicated. You'll either need to store [smart]pointers to elements, or provide a custom allocator. The former method is not memory efficient, and the later is my own invention(pitfalls are unknown).
